# type error : 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: pandas

**the o/p of a column of df['emp_years'] is:-**

```
   NaN

 < 1 year 

  3 years

 10+ years

 10+ years

         ...    

 9 years

10+ years

  1 year

 3 years

 3 years
```

Name: emp_years, Length: 10000, dtype: object

**now when i try to implement this function on this column**

```py
def change(col):
    for x in col:
        print(x)

        
df['emp_years'].apply(change)
```

i get type error TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
so can someone tell me how to solve this

Comment: If you could also mention what output you are expecting it will be easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly appears when there are NaN values in the column. When you try to access/ print NaN values, this error message is given. I would advice you to clean the data a little bit. One solution is to drop your NaN values of that column. For that use `df.dropna(subset=['emp_years'])`. I don't know whether you have changed some data types but I would advice you to do that and next time do provide more info about the dataset or provide some link to your code so that we can understand the issue better.
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using vectorisation.

Have a look at `df.iterrows()` or `df.itertuples()` as described in the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples